# ffmpeg being called via PHP exec batch file

Tags: php, image, batch-file, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I'm using ffmpeg to extract images from a video file through PHP shell_exec method. This is all ok except if the image already exsists then ffmpeg won't overwrite it even with the -y option in the ffmpeg command. I think it has something to do with shell_exec though because if I execute the bat by clicking on it then all is well with the batch file. Anybody ever had this problem? Any imput would be greatly apprciated. maybe I should just use a del statment to delete the image if it exsits before ffmpeg has a chance to run. Input please.

--calmchess

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permission issue to me.

Just do a quick check via terminal to check the permission of the old file(`ls -l`). Make sure you(user: `apache`) have write access to all the files under question via php.

Comment: not a permissions problem I'm using IIS 8 if I delete the file manually then there is no problem. troublesome bug

Comment: well i found the problem my batch file copies the video file before it extracts the image but the file being copied is corrupt I have a feeling I'm not waiting until the video file is finished being created before I try to copy it therefore corrupting it.

Comment: here is that batch file I'm using [code]copy  "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Media Server 5\applications\video_chat\streams\room0\stream00.flv" C:\webserver\dev\book\images\stream00.flv
cd C:\webserver\dev\book\images
C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg.exe -i  stream00.flv -f  image2  -s  258x176  -vframes 1  stream0.jpg 
[/code]

Comment: fixed it by closing the stream before ffmpeg runs ----so many wasted hours. I love this job!

Comment: Good to know that you have finally fixed it. There is nothing better than fixing the issue our-self because learning during that process pays-off in long run.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by closing the stream before ffmpeg runs ----so many wasted hours. I love this job!